# undefined column in rails many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i defined a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between my 2 models as shown below

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :first_name, :last_name, :email
  has_and_belongs_to_many :themes, class_name: 'XY::Theme'
end

class XY::Theme < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :clients
end
```

then i defined my join table from the active record rails guide like this

```
class CreateClientsThemesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients_xy_themes, id: false do |t|
        t.integer :client_id
        t.integer :xy_theme_id
    end
    add_index :clients_xy_themes, :client_id
    add_index :clients_xy_themes, :xy_theme_id
  end
end
```

but when i try to access the themes from clients table in rails console, iget this error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column clients_xy_themes.theme_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ER JOIN "clients_xy_themes" ON "xy_themes"."id" = "clients_v...
```

why is this happening? My migration specifically stated the keys on the themes table , but its trying to access a column that doesnt exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **convention** is, if your relation name is `themes`, then the foreign key name would be `theme_id`.

You could define the relation like:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :xy_themes, class_name: 'XY::Theme'
```

Or you have to define the `association_foreign_key` option.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :themes, class_name: 'XY::Theme', association_foreign_key: 'xy_theme_id'
```

Comment: thank you!  defining the foreign association worked!

Comment: I've ran into more trouble again, if i try to go from theme to clients by doing  theme.clients, it gives me the same error as above for theme_id. i've tried putting association_foreign_key "client_id" for themes but it doesnt work. suggestions?

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer Try use `foreign_key: 'xy_theme_id'`